# Why did Ashwatthama fight for Kauravas?

Tags: mahabharata

Ashwatthama is considered as an avatar of Lord Shiva. 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashwatthama

Inspite of being Rudramsha, why did he side with adharmis like Kauravas?

Comment: According to Adi parva of Mahabharata (1.61), Ashwatthama was born from portions of Mahādeva, Death, Lust (kAma), and Fury (krodha), which merged into one....... mahAdevAntakAbhyAM cha kAmAtkrodhAchcha bhArata | ekatvamupapannAnAM jaj~ne shUraH parantapaH || 66|| ashvatthAmA mahAvIryaH shatrupakShakShaya~NkaraH | vIraH kamalapatrAkShaH kShitAvAsInnarAdhipa || 67||